# Using trim function on table references

Tags: excel, formula, dashboard

I'm attempting to aggregate from an imported data source in excel. I have 2 combo boxes that specify conditions for a sumifs function (selected using offsets).

Where I struggle is that the data doesn't seem to match unless I use a trim function (I tested this on by adding a column to the data table).

The following formula always returns 0

```
=SUMIFS(Table_ExternalData_1[RedFlag],Table_ExternalData_1[RAGSTATUS],"=trim("&ReconAggregation!$A4&")",Table_ExternalData_1[ClientDescription],"=trim("&OFFSET(Lists!$A$1,Lists!$B$1,0)&")", Table_ExternalData_1[AgencyDescription],"=trim("&OFFSET(Lists!$C$1,Lists!$D$1,0)&")")
```

when I add the trims

```
=SUMIFS(Table_ExternalData_1[RedFlag],trim(Table_ExternalData_1[RAGSTATUS]),"=trim("&ReconAggregation!$A4&")",trim(Table_ExternalData_1[ClientDescription]),"=trim("&OFFSET(Lists!$A$1,Lists!$B$1,0)&")", trim(Table_ExternalData_1[AgencyDescription]),"=trim("&OFFSET(Lists!$C$1,Lists!$D$1,0)&")")
```

it tells me that I have a formula error. Any idea why? Is there a better way to do this?

Cheers,

G

Comment: It turns out that I didn't need the "=" on the right hand side of the formulas. Cheers all

Answer (score 0):

> it tells me that I have a formula error

Maybe there's problem with your `"`

```
=SUMIFS(Table_ExternalData_1[RedFlag],trim(Table_ExternalData_1[RAGSTATUS]),"=trim('&ReconAggregation!$A4&')",trim(Table_ExternalData_1[ClientDescription]),"=trim('&OFFSET(Lists!$A$1,Lists!$B$1,0)&')", trim(Table_ExternalData_1[AgencyDescription]),"=trim('&OFFSET(Lists!$C$1,Lists!$D$1,0)&')")
```

Answer (score 0):

As It happens, the "=" were not required on the right hand side. This was found through trial and error. Still unsure as to why the trim function on the left prompted an error, but with additional cleansing of the source data it wasn't required. Thanks all for your input.